# Connect MacBook Pro 13 late 2012 SSD to SATA?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, sata

I have an SSD hard drive from MacBook Pro late 2012 (A1425). Is there a possibility to somehow connect it to a normal PC through SATA, PCIe etc.?

Comment: what is "normal PC" ? Toshiba, Asus, Dell and so on... Model ? connect as build in or external drive ?

Comment: "Normal PC" is a PC with SATA connector for hard drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be possible.
According to [this iFixit tear down](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2012+Teardown/11225), the A1425 SSD

> It's a Samsung MZ-DPC2560/0A2 unit, rated at 3.3 volts and 2.39 amps. The serial number reads S0X5NYAC703706.

[image: mSATA SSD]

Which appears to have an mSATA connector.
There are lots of mSATA to whatever-you-may-need adapters on the market.

mSATA to micro SATA ([1](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/msata-to-micro-sata-adapter)) ([2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G8772CS))

[mSATA USB enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LRZPNHM)

I haven't tried any of this myself, just did a search for it.

---

This question [28 pin SSD adapter or enclosure needed for Late 2014 MBP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164755/28-pin-ssd-adapter-or-enclosure-needed-for-late-2014-mbp) points to certain incompatibilities to be aware of before buying.